# strtotime not working when giving a manual date

Tags: php, date, time, difference

I want to see the difference between two hours, but when the user doesn't logout I give it a manual hour in a string, then I tried to convert it into time and check the difference. However the result is always `$d_time_in` even though the two strings are not empty and they have the same format.

```
      $start_timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $_POST[selectMonth], $_POST[selectDay], $_POST[selectYear]);

$end_timestamp = $start_timestamp + 86399;

$q1 = "SELECT c.user_id, c.date, c.time_in, c.time_out, u.user_firstname, u.user_lastname 
        FROM control_time c 
            LEFT JOIN user u
                ON u.user_id = c.user_id
            WHERE c.date >= $start_timestamp AND c.date <= $end_timestamp";
$r1 = mysql_query($q1) or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($r1);

if($num_rows > 0){
    $display .= "<table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"1\" cellpadding=\"4\">

                      <tr>
                        <td bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\"><strong>Usuario</strong></td>   
                        <td bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\"><strong>Fecha</strong></td> 
                        <td bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\"><strong>Ingreso</strong></td>   
                        <td bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\"><strong>Salida</strong></td>    
                        <td bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\"><strong>Trabajadas</strong></td>    
                        </tr>";
    while($time_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($r1)){

        if($time_info[time_in] > ($time_info[date]+34200)){
            $in_bg = "#F3F781";
        }else{
            $in_bg = "#DDDDDD";
        }
        //specify time in 
        $d_time_in = date("G:i a", $time_info[time_in]);

        if($time_info[time_out] == 0){
            if(date('w', $time_info[date]) == 6){
                $d_time_out = '15:00 pm';
            }else{
                $d_time_out = '19:00 pm';
            }
            $out_time = strtotime($d_time_out);
            $out_bg = "#F5DA81";
        }else{
            $d_time_out = date("G:i a", $time_info[time_out]);
            $out_time = strtotime($d_time_out);
            $out_bg = "#DDDDDD";
        }

        $difference_hours = strtotime($d_time_in) - $out_time;
        if($difference_hours != 0){
            $d_time_worked = date("G:i",$difference_hours);
        }else{
            $d_time_worked= "00:00";
        }
        $display .= "
                      <tr>
                        <td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">$time_info[user_firstname] $time_info[user_lastname]</td>
                        <td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">".date("d-m-y", $time_info[date])."</td>
                        <td bgcolor=\"$in_bg\">$d_time_in</td>
                        <td bgcolor=\"$out_bg\">$d_time_out</td>
                        <td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">$d_time_worked</td>
                      </tr>";
    }
    $display .= "</table>";
}
```

Comment: Huh, are your `time_out` and `time_in` const? Otherwise you should at least get several PHP warnings.

Comment: both are time stamps then converted in date format in php

Comment: No, I mean the literal `time_out` and `time_in`. If you use `$time_out` and `$time_in` or `TIME_OUT` and `TIME_IN` I would not ask that question...

Comment: I edited with the whole code so you can see. time out and time in are only use on a array the time in and time out gives me the correct info but the problem comes when trying to see the difference between the two.

Comment: I mean, PHP variables _should_ start with `$`, and your `time_out` and `time_in` do not start with it, and they also are not in upper case, so I wonder if they are constants, or have you miss-typed the `$`...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say where is the problem.

But try to test the last block and comment the whole upper code.

```
$difference_hours = strtotime($d_time_in) - strtotime($d_time_out);
```

Set these $d_time_in and $d_time_out to two constant timestamps.

If this code works well (you get the time difference) than go to the upper block and test it.

```
$d_time_in = date("G:i a", $time_info[time_in]);
```

The same logic. Test with two preset definite timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after going over it 100 times more I found the solution here it is.

```
$start_timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $_POST[selectMonth], $_POST[selectDay], $_POST[selectYear]);

$end_timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $_POST[selectMonthE], $_POST[selectDayE], $_POST[selectYearE]);

$end_timestamp = $end_timestamp + 86399;

$q1 = "SELECT c.user_id, c.date, c.time_in, c.time_out, u.user_firstname, u.user_lastname 
        FROM control_time c 
            LEFT JOIN user u
                ON u.user_id = c.user_id
            WHERE c.date >= $start_timestamp AND c.date <= $end_timestamp";
$r1 = mysql_query($q1) or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($r1);

if($num_rows > 0){
    $display .= "<table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"1\" cellpadding=\"4\">

                      <tr>
                        <td bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\"><strong>Usuario</strong></td>   
                        <td bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\"><strong>Fecha</strong></td> 
                        <td bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\"><strong>Ingreso</strong></td>   
                        <td bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\"><strong>Salida</strong></td>    
                        <td bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\"><strong>Trabajadas</strong></td>    
                        </tr>";
    while($time_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($r1)){

        if($time_info[time_in] > ($time_info[date]+34200)){
            $in_bg = "#F3F781";
        }else{
            $in_bg = "#DDDDDD";
        }
        //specify time in 
        $d_time_in = date("G:i:s", $time_info[time_in]);
        $in_time = strtotime($d_time_in);
        //specify time out
        if($time_info[time_out] == 0){
            //if time out is equal to 0 lets set it manually
            if(date('w', $time_info[date]) == 6){
                //if its saturday
                $d_time_out = '15:00:00';
            }else{
                //if its any other day
                $d_time_out = '19:00:00';
            }
            //convert out hour to time
            $out_time = strtotime($d_time_out);
            $out_bg = "#F5DA81";
        }else{
            //if time out != 0
            $d_time_out = date("G:i:s", $time_info[time_out]);

            //convert out hour to time
            $out_time = strtotime($d_time_out);
            $out_bg = "#DDDDDD";
        }
        //see differente between the two
        $difference_hours = $out_time - $in_time;

        if($difference_hours > 0){
            //show how many hours worked
            $d_time_worked = gmdate("H:i:s", $difference_hours);;
        }else{
            $d_time_worked= "00:00";
        }
        $display .= "
                      <tr>
                        <td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">$time_info[user_firstname] $time_info[user_lastname]</td>
                        <td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">".date("d-m-y", $time_info[date])."</td>
                        <td bgcolor=\"$in_bg\">$d_time_in</td>
                        <td bgcolor=\"$out_bg\">$d_time_out</td>
                        <td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\">$d_time_worked</td>
                      </tr>";
    }
    $display .= "</table>";
}
```

thanks all for helping!